# Accordion position and scrollto

Tags: jquery

I have the following accordion working but having trouble figuring out how to make the first item not scroll to first item position which is on the middle of the page.

I want the following items in the accordion to scroll up to next item start when clicked. Also when any item is opened and closed the code no longer works.

But if you select items without closing open item then code works smoothly. Thanks for any assistance.

```
$("#accord_holder").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible:true,
    navigation:true,
    active:false,
    change: function(event, ui) {
    $(window).scrollTop(ui.newHeader.position().top - 1);
    }
   });
```

Comment: try replicating your problem here jsbin.com

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rwyvh/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the error

change this

```
  $(window).scrollTop(ui.newHeader.position().top - 1);
```

into

```
   $(window).scrollTop(ui.newHeader.position.top - 50);
```

Updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rwyvh/37/

Comment: That got rid of the opening/closing problem but it scrolls/jumps to top of page when post first items are selected

Comment: just read this article. I already covered this here

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4aac15/smooth-scrolling-effect-in-javascript-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#accord_holder").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible:true,
    navigation:true,
    active:false,
    change: function(event, ui) {
     //this might work
     $(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollHeight);
    }
   });
```

Comment: That takes care of the opening/closing problem but eliminates the scrolling altogether.

Comment: People that give mark downs without any comment as to why really frustrate me ;)